# margin inside the edit text in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, margin, textview

My question is : I have an EditText and I want set a margin inside the EditText, I mean margin for the content (the text) of the edit text, not a margin for a the view witch I can resolve by this attribute : `android:layout_marginLeft`.

I need let some space before and after the text inside the EditText.

I tried to set the padding, but doesn't work !

this is my xml code :

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp">

    <EditText android:inputType="none"
        android:textSize="15sp" 
        android:id="@+id/editText1" 
        android:scrollHorizontally="true" 
        android:layout_height="35dp"  
        android:padding="3dip" 
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_width="160dp" 
        android:layout_weight="0" />

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/refreshButton" 
        android:src="@drawable/refresh" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Can any one help me to do that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 83, accepted):

The padding variable should be exactly what you are looking for. You should try to increase the padding to something like 10dp just to test if it does anything. I'm guessing that because the background of the EditText is a 9 patch the padding is not acting how you would expect. When you set padding on a view with a 9 patch as the background any padding that is built into the 9 patch is than ignored. So if the 9 patch has 5dp padding and you set 3dp padding in the xml you will not get 8dp padding you will get 3dp.

Comment: Beariing in mind that these days (2016) this answer has the problem of changing the padding on the text, without doing the same to the background drawable. Which could look strange depending on the background (e.g. AppCompat base EditText style)